# Java Packages importing .inc file

Tags: java, package

As In the case of JSPs,Is there any way to use a .inc file to import all the required classes from 3rd party libraries in a java class

Comment: usually you can import full packages (eg: import org.apache.whatever.*;) with <%@page import="org.apache.whatever."%> but really, you shouldn't be importing nothing but javabeans in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of including .nic file in Java classes.

You can always include a JAR inside project lib directory, external jar or Libraries. You can right click project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab.

And then import required classes from included Jars using import statement.

Comment: It seems,my question is not clear. Briefly, suppose If I want to import 50 classes from 50 packages in my java class,and my java class contains 100 lines of code,it looks absurd. Instead of writing all import statements in my java source file,Is there any way so that I can declare all imports in a file and I can use this file in my java source file?I hope my question is clear now